# What would cause a ColdFusion website to error in only one browser, on only one computer?

Tags: macos, java, osx-mountain-lion, safari, coldfusion

I'm using a MacBook Pro running OS X Mountain Lion.  A particular website I am trying to visit gives me ColdFusion/Java errors anytime I try to access any of its pages.  For a while I thought it was a problem with the website, but then I did some troubleshooting and noticed something really weird.  The problem only occurs in Safari, and only on this machine.  If I use any other browser on this machine, or I use Safari from a different machine (physical or even virtual), the website loads just fine.

Based on that, I'm inclined to think that whatever the problem is, it's with my computer and has nothing to do with the specific website.  Basically what I'm looking for, and for some reason could not find in a Google search, is just some generic suggestions of what could possibly be wrong with my system to cause such an unusual problem.  Right now I don't know how to begin to troubleshoot this, so if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.  For example, is there any software that is known to interfere with Safari and ColdFusion?  Could it be related to my installation of Creative Cloud somehow?

Thanks in advance for any pointers you can give.  Some brainstorming would really help me out here.

EDIT:  Posted a screenshot of the full error by request.[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: It would be helpful to see the errors.

Comment: I am a ColdFusion developer and would LOVE to see the error. Please copy and paste it.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the error, thought it would look neater than a copy/paste.  Just keep in mind, I'm not the developer for this website, so I can only experiment with my own system, not with the website.